# too much error correction made the code more worse

Tags: python-3.x

This is my first time with python and I have written this program to simulate a node trying to find mobile phones in an area.
first i am taking the distance converting them to RSS and based on that deciding the direction of the node to find all mobile phones.
the code worked fine till 2 days ago but when i expanded to area and no of nodes, some errors started to come and i kept correcting them.
now it doesn't run and I have made it more worse:
is there any hint or guidance I can get from the experts?
and yes I have overwritten the code without saving it to some other place.
Or maybe someone can really help me by having a look at it.
its really messy though.
thanks

Here is a part of the code i am having the most trouble with.

```
def pos_y(uav_current_cord,area,uav_step_size,flag):
detected_y = 0
detected_nodes_pos_y = 0 
if flag == 1:
    span = area+uav_step_size -  uav_current_cord[1]  
    #print(span)
    for y in range(uav_current_cord[1],area+uav_step_size,uav_step_size):
        global distance_covered 
        distance_covered += uav_step_size             
        UAV_new = [uav_current_cord[0],y]
        y_last_pos = UAV_new        
        plot((*UAV_new), marker='o', color='r', ls='')
        distance_new=[]
        for i in nodes:
            temp_x_axis = euclid_dist(UAV_new,node_cord[i]) 
            ss_x_axis = dist_to_ss(temp_x_axis)
            if (ss_x_axis > threshold):
                detected_nodes_pos_y += 1
        detected_y = (detected_nodes_pos_y)

    if y >= area+uav_step_size:
        uav_current_cord = UAV_new
        flag = 1
        keep_moving = neg_x(uav_current_cord,span,uav_step_size,flag,y_last_pos)
        uav_current_new = keep_moving[0]
        distance_covered_back = keep_moving[1]
        nodes_detected_final = keep_moving[2]
        uav_current_new = keep_moving[3]
        #return [uav_current_new, distance_covered, nodes_detected_final, uav_current_new]     
        #uav_current_new = y_last_pos
    return [y_last_pos, distance_covered, detected_y, y_last_pos]
if flag == 1:
    area1 = area*2
for y in range(uav_current_cord[1],area,uav_step_size):
    UAV_new = [uav_current_cord[0],y]
    #print('Pos_Y movement of UAV',UAV_new)
    #print('ye loop chal raha hai')
    y_last_pos = UAV_new        
    plot((*UAV_new), marker='o', color='g', ls='')
    distance_new=[]
    for i in nodes:
        temp_x_axis = euclid_dist(UAV_new,node_cord[i]) 
        ss_x_axis = dist_to_ss(temp_x_axis)
        if (ss_x_axis > threshold):
            detected_nodes_pos_y += 1
    detected_y = (detected_nodes_pos_y)
    #print('nodes detected in pos Y  ',detected_y)    
    #print('last position in pos y =', y_last_pos)  
for y in range(UAV_new[1],uav_current_cord[1],-uav_step_size):
   # print('ab ye chala hai')
    UAV_new=[uav_current_cord[0],y]
    plot((*UAV_new), marker='o', color='g', ls='')
distance_covered_back = area*2
return [UAV_new, distance_covered_back, detected_y, y_last_pos]
```

Comment: *Oooh...* And you haven't yet learned about `git`, have you? (`git` is a very fine version-control system ... Google it ... which would have let you "snapshot" the code when you started out and then, by a series of "commits," have captured all of your changes.) Most unfortunately, if you *didn't* do such a thing, I'm sorry to say that **you, alone** now have a (koff, koff ... *most* familiar) problem. First of all, try to get back to where you *were.* Then, learn about `git`. ### *(P.S.: I'm entirely sensitive to your plight and am **not** trying to be cute.)*

Comment: @YOU, and if the code was added to the question.. Do you know where to go back (other than completely rewrite the code to what the OP wants if that is clear)?

Comment: well, i don't assume anything before seeing the code.

Comment: well thanks i will surely have a look at git. and about the code its really messed up sometimes I myself get lost and then I have to start from the beginning. I have started to sort it out step by step hopefully it will make sense after that.

Comment: I am working on it since yesterday and Its working better than before but the following two errors are always coming up.
If I correct them some other errors come. I will try to put the code here. Anyways these are the errors I mentioned above.
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
local variable 'x_updated' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, use `git`, but know the alternatives.

If you're brand new to revision control, starting with Git will either be a big help or hindrance in the time being, but learning Git will be valuable down the line regardless.

If you have an MSDN account, you can also use Visual Studio's built-in revision control. It's good for rapid prototyping, but has no real edge over git.

Another common choice that is pretty simple would be TortoiseSVN. It's very easy to use.

Alternatively, if you don't mind your code being public for a free account or a small monthly fee for private, you can do all your commits via browser using GitHub. This is hand's down the simplest option for revision control newbies. It's major downside is limited flexibility for multi-file commits.

I have little to no meaningful experience with BitBucket and some other common alternatives to GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but we cannot help you... You're not the first with this problem and unfortunately not the last.

To help prevent this kind of problems, software like [Git](https://git-scm.com/) exists. It let's you do the following ([image reference](https://git-scm.com/about/branching-and-merging)):

[image]

The root file is the *master*. This is your working script. If you want to change/add/remove something, you make a so-called *branch* where you do whatever you want. If you have tested it, you can *commit* the changes (that is, store this as a new version of the script with a comment) and *merge* it with the master (that is, add the changes to the master script). If something seems to be wrong, you can always go back to a previous version of your script.

The [documentation](https://git-scm.com/doc) of Git is very good: read it and use it wisely!